# Two Filters for one column in power apps

Tags: powerapps

I'm trying this but not working

```
Filter(
  Employees,
  StartsWith("cr_city",TextInput1.Text ) && ("cr_city"= TextInput2.Text ))
```

also tried with Search and without StartsWith.. but no success..
I have two search boxes for city and the Gallery should load the both results.

what's the best(easy) way for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the gallery to show the employees with city in TextInput1 **or** TextInput2, you should use the Or operator (`Or` or `||`), not And (`And` or `&&`):

```
Filter(
    Employees,
    StartsWith("cr_city", TextInput1.Text) Or ("cr_city"= TextInput2.Text ))
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm trying to get both at the same time (And) and its not working.. don't know why? for example i need all employees from Dallas and Portland to be on display.

Comment: not sure why but it worked with OR :D not with AND.. may be some king of reversed logic :D   Worked for me like that : Filter(Employees, "Dallas" in city || "Portland" in city)

Comment: Glad to hear that it's working. With the And operator, you were filtering the employees for those whose city are *both* Portland and Dallas - and they cannot be in the two places at once, so you wouldn't get any employees. By using the Or operator, you are filtering by those that are in *either* of those cities, which is what you need.